# Gravação de arquivo a partir de stream-webcam

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js, file-upload, stream

Eu tenho uma dúvida quanto meu código de stream com getusermedia.

Eu quero enviar para meu servidor Node.js uma gravação da minha webcam.

O meu formulário recebe um vídeo que posso fazer com upload, mas teria uma segunda função -gravar um vídeo da webcam e enviar ele salvo como file do formulário.

Então só pra explicar melhor. Meu campo file do formulário deveria receber um arquivo de video gravado da webcam para envio pro servidor, como alternativa de envio.

Vou postar aqui o arquivo de html e meu script, meu script esta sendo jogado dentro do arquivo html como tag . O formulário em Node.js já esta pronto, só preciso mesmo criar o vídeo com a webcam.

Caso seja muito complicado enviar o record como arquivo direto para o field file do formulário, ele pode ser disponibilizado para download mesmo e depois o usuario insere ele no formulario manualmente. O importante é essa stream ser salva de alguma forma.

Para explicar a função Record() é invocada acionando a webcam. Depois disso eu queria um botão com um "Start" pra começar a gravar a partir daquele ponto.
Apos isso, pode ser um segundo botão com "Stop" finalizaria a gravação e solicitaria o download ou ativaria o envio do arquivo direto pro field file.

Ps. Primeira vez com o uso de stream, então ainda estou bem lerdo no assunto.

Eis minhas linhas até o momento:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function Record(){

 window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
 navigator.getUserMedia = 
  navigator.getUserMedia ||
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
  navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
  navigator.msGetUserMedia;
 var video = document.querySelector('video');
 var cameraStream = '';
 if(navigator.getUserMedia){
  navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true, video:true},
   function(stream){
    cameraStream = stream;
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);},
   function(){document.writeln("problema para acessar a camera!");});
 }

 else{
  document.writeln("Recurso não suportado por seu navegador!");
 }



}

</script>
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="cont fl">
  <h1>Video Uploader | Recorder</h1>

  <div class="fl form">
  <form action="/resform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <div>
    <h1>Your Name:</h1>
    <input type="text" class="inps" name="nome">
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>e-mail:</h1>
    <input type="email" class="inps" name="email">
   </div>
   <div class="bt">
    <div class="fr">
     
     <input type="file" value="Upload" name="file" >
     
    </div>
    

   </div>
   <hr style="width:90%;float:left;">
   <input class="fl" type="submit" value="Confirm" name="sub">

  </form>  
  </div>

<div class="form fr" style="width:300px">
 <video autoplay width="280" height="160">
 <canvas width="280" height="160">
 </canvas></video>
 <button onclick="drawVideoFrame()">Record</button>
 <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
 <button onclick="Record()">Turn On</button>
</div>
</div>
```